# Download folders and sub-folders using SFTP with SharpSSH

Tags: c#, directory, sftp

```
sFTP folder structure:

MainFolder
|_FolderA
  |_sub1
    |_file1.txt
  |_sub1
    |_file2.txt  
  .
  .
  .
  |_sub-n
    |_filen.txt     

|_FolderB
  |_sub1
    |_file3.txt
  |_sub1
    |_file4.txt
  .
  .
  .
  |_sub-n
    |_filen.txt
```

Using Tamir's dll, can the above folder structure be downloaded from sftp?

```
using Tamir.Sharpssh;
using Tamir.Streams;
try
{
  .
  .
  .
  string[] s = Directory.GetFiles(ftpfolder,"*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
  for(int i=0; i< s.length; i++)
  {
    osftp.Get(ftpfolder + s[i], localfolder + Path.GetfileName(s.[i]));
  }
}
catch(IOException copyError)
{
   logg(copyerror.message);

}
```

logg() is a function for logging errors encountered.

Tried generating errorlogs but none were logged. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: What errors/exceptions do you get? What happens and what would you expect to happen?

Comment: i'm expecting it would download the text files recursively on my local @ChrFin

Comment: Does the folder exist locally? Any exceptions or what happens?

Comment: folder does not exists locally. i need to download it from sftp to my local @ChrFin

Comment: I THINK you need to create the folder first, before you can download a file into it...

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#csharp) it's pretty well documented with some nice examples... SharpSSH is very old and I believe no longer maintained / out of date...

Here's an example of usage...

```
using System;
using WinSCP;

class Example
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
            HostName = EdiConfiguration.FtpIpAddressOrHostName,
            UserName = EdiConfiguration.FtpUserName,
            Password = EdiConfiguration.FtpPassword,
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = EdiConfiguration.SshHostKeyFingerprint,
            PortNumber = EdiConfiguration.FtpPortNumber
        };

        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            session.Open(sessionOptions);

            TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;
            transferOptions.ResumeSupport.State = TransferResumeSupportState.Off;

            // Download the files in the OUT directory.
            TransferOperationResult transferOperationResult = session.GetFiles(EdiConfiguration.FtpDirectory, EdiConfiguration.IncommingFilePath, false, transferOptions);

            // Check and throw if there are any errors with the transfer operation.
            transferOperationResult.Check();

            // Remove files that have been downloaded.
            foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferOperationResult.Transfers)
            {
                RemovalOperationResult removalResult = session.RemoveFiles(session.EscapeFileMask(transfer.FileName));

                if (!removalResult.IsSuccess)
                {
                    eventLogUtility.WriteToEventLog("There was an error removing the file: " + transfer.FileName + " from " + sessionOptions.HostName + ".", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: let me check it out and will get back here asap thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you copy files and directories recursively like 'scp -r user@host:/dir/on/remote C:\dir\on\local\', you can do this as follows.

```
using Tamir.SharpSsh;

var host = "host address";
var user = @"user account";
var password = @"user password";
var scp = new Scp( host, user, password );
scp.Connect();
scp.Recursive = true;
var remotePath = @"/dir/on/remote";
var localPath = @"C:\dir\on\local\";
scp.Get( remotePath, localPath );
scp.Close();
```